# the difference in meaning between 'the way ... is', 'as ... is' and 'like'

Tags: writing

> The moon is not a magnet the way the earth is.

Can I rewrite the sentence like as:

> The moon is not a magnet as the earth is.

or

> The moon is not a magnet, like the earth.

Comment: How is the moon a magnet? I'm curious to know the source of this.

Comment: @ Varun KN, The magnetic field of the Moon is very weak in comparison to that of the Earth.

Comment: That I know, But can anything that has a magnetic field be called a magnet?

Comment: Rather than a scientific fact, I'd like to know whether the sentences have the same meaning.